# HTML form (python, flask): have a button submit a unique parameter to method

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a good HTML form right now that calls a method via a button.

What I want to do is create several new buttons that call the same method, but each pass a different parameter.

The specific use case is: my button right now retrieves a random album with `get_random_album()`.

I want to make a "Jazz", "Classical", and "Rock" buttons that respectively call `get_random_album(genre=<genre>)`.

MVE:

```
from flask import Flask,redirect
# Below import commented out for MVE
# from discogs import get_random_album

# TODO: look at more advanced form builders

# Create app instance
app = Flask(__name__)

# Create homepage with button
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return """
    <html><body>
    <h2> Spin yo records </h2>
        <form action="/query">
            <input type='submit' value="I'm Feeling Lucky">
    </body></html>
    """

# Backend query to discogs
@app.route("/query")
def link():
    # return redirect(get_random_album())
    # Real implementation commented out
    # Scratch implementation here
    def get_random_album(genre=None):
        url = "https://www.google.com" 
        if genre == 'Jazz':
            return url + "/search?q=jazz"
        if genre == 'Classical':
            return url + "/search?q=classical"
        if genre == 'Rock':
            return url + "/search?q=rock"
        return url

    return redirect(get_random_album())
# Run app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,port=600)
```

[Actual project](https://github.com/christina-zhou-96/SpinYoRecords)

Comment: in `<form>` you can use hidden `<input>` with needed value or `<select>`  to select value from list. If you need many buttons on page then you can create many forms and every form will have own button and hidden `<input> ` with different value. And later you use `request.form.get("name_of_hidden_input")` to get this value in flask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create buttons with the same `name` but with different `value`

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return """
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2> Spin yo records </h2>

        <form action="/query">
            <input type="submit" name="selected_genre" value="Jazz">
            <input type="submit" name="selected_genre" value="Classic">
            <input type="submit" name="selected_genre" value="Rock">
            <input type="submit" name="selected_genre" value="I'm Feeling Lucky">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    """
```

And next you can get selected `value` using `request` and name used in buttons

```
from flask import request
import random

@app.route("/query")
def link():
    allowed_values = ('Jazz', 'Classic', 'Rock')

    genre = request.args.get("selected_genre")

    # "I'm Feeling Lucky"
    if genre not in allowed_values:
        genre = random.choice(allowed_values)

    genre = genre.lower()

    url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={genre}" 

    return redirect(url)
```

---

Full example

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, request
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return """
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2> Spin yo records </h2>

        <form action="/query">
            <input type="submit" name="selected_genre" value="Jazz">
            <input type="submit" name="selected_genre" value="Classic">
            <input type="submit" name="selected_genre" value="Rock">
            <input type="submit" name="selected_genre" value="I'm Feeling Lucky">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    """


@app.route("/query")
def link():
    allowed_values = ('Jazz', 'Classic', 'Rock')

    genre = request.args.get("selected_genre")

    if genre not in allowed_values:
        genre = random.choice(allowed_values)

    genre = genre.lower()

    url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={genre}" 

    return redirect(url)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,port=600)
```

---

In previous version it sends `value` in url ie. `/query?selected_genre=Rock` - so everyone can see it or easily it can try to use own value. And this is why I used `allowed_values` to block it.

To hide selected genre from url you have to use:

- `<form ... method="POST">`
- `@app.route(..., methods=['GET', 'POST'])` (or `methods=['POST']`)
- `request.form` instead of `request.args`

---

Full example

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, request
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return """
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2> Spin yo records </h2>

        <form action="/query" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" name="selected_genre" value="Jazz">
            <input type="submit" name="selected_genre" value="Classic">
            <input type="submit" name="selected_genre" value="Rock">
            <input type="submit" name="selected_genre" value="I'm Feeling Lucky">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    """

@app.route("/query", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def link():
    allowed_values = ('Jazz', 'Classic', 'Rock')

    genre = request.form.get("selected_genre")

    if genre not in allowed_values:
        genre = random.choice(allowed_values)

    genre = genre.lower()

    url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={genre}" 

    return redirect(url)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=600)
```

---

If you want to use different text on button but still send the same `value` then you may need hidden `<input>` with `value` but then every button will need seprated `<form>`

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return """
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2> Spin yo records </h2>

        <form action="/query" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" value="Jazz" name="selected_genre">
            <input type="submit" value="The Best Jazz Music">
        </form>

        <form action="/query" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" value="Classic" name="selected_genre">
            <input type="submit" value="The Best Classic Music">
        </form>

        <form action="/query" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" value="Rock" name="selected_genre">
            <input type="submit" value="The Best Rock Music">
        </form>

        <form action="/query" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" value="random" name="selected_genre">
            <input type="submit" value="I'm Feeling Lucky">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    """
```

Or you have to use `<button>` instead of `<input>`

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return """
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2> Spin yo records </h2>
        <form action="/query" method="POST">
            <button type="submit" name="selected_genre" value="Jazz">The Best Jazz Music</button>
            <button type="submit" name="selected_genre" value="Classic">The Best Classic Music</button>
            <button type="submit" name="selected_genre" value="Rock">The Best Rock Music</button>
            <button type="submit" name="selected_genre" value="random">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    """
```